# Getting segmentation fault when calling a virtual function on a derived class

Tags: c++

I'm getting segmentation fault for this short code and I'm not able to figure out why.

```
class XorY {
public:
    virtual void set_cost(double& cost){}

};
class X_based:public XorY {
public:
    X_based(int _x):x(_x){}
    void set_cost(double& cost)
    {
        cost=cost*(100-x)/100;
    }
    int x;
};
class Y_based:public XorY
{       
    public:
        Y_based(){}
        Y_based(int _y): y(_y){}
        void set_cost(double& cost){
            cost=cost-y;
        }
        int y;
};


int main(){
    double a=2;
    XorY* type;
    Y_based* ptr;
    *ptr=Y_based(3);
    type=ptr;
    type->set_cost(a);
}
```

It seems that there's an error with this line

```
*ptr=Y_based(3);
```

When I change it to

```
ptr=&Y_based(3);
```

I get this compile error:

```
taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what does `ptr` point to when you do this? `*ptr=Y_based(3);`.

Comment: I'm trying to make it point to an object from Y_based class.I'm calling it's constructor to do so

Comment: @Ghazal.S, dereferencing a pointer that has not been initialized or set to point to a valid object leads to undefined behavior. In your case, `ptr` is such a pointer.

Comment: Hint 2: do you need pointers anyway?

Comment: @RSahu Thank you after allocating some memory for the pointers I don't get the segmentation fault any more.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because I want to call the virtual set_cost() function on objects of XorY class in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the line

```
*ptr=Y_based(3);
```

is incorrect. I suppose, you meant that the `ptr` pointer should point to the new object of type `Y_based` after this operation.

Hovewer, the meaning of this line is different.

First, the right part (`Y_based(3)`) is calculated. It's an object of type `Y_based` with `_y` field equal to `3`. After that, the left part (`*ptr`) is calculated. It's the object which is pointed by `ptr` pointer and it's undefined since the pointer was not initialized. If the pointer was initialized, after that the value of the right part would be assigned to the value of the left part. That is, the object pointed by `ptr` would change, not the pointer itself.

Your desirable behavior can be achieved by writing

```
ptr = new Y_based(3);
```

Here the left part, which is assigned to, it not the object pointed by `ptr`, but `ptr` itself, and the right part is a pointer to a newly created object of type `Y_based`.

Also, since the object of type `Y_based` was created by the `new` keyword, it will not be destroyed after you leave the block, and you should take care of it manually, using `delete` at a line where you don't need the object anymore. To correctly destroy an object by the pointer to the base class, you should also define a virtual destructor in the base class:

```
class XorY {
public:
    virtual void set_cost(double& cost){}
    virtual ~XorY() = default;
};
```

If you don't want to bother with all this stuff, but still need to have a polymorphic behavior, you can use a reference instead of a pointer:

```
int main(){
    double a=2;
    Y_based& ptr = Y_based(3);
    XorY& type = ptr;
    type.set_cost(a);
}
```

Comment: Yeah now I get it.Thanks a lot :) @alexeykuzmin0